# Trace page table access of a Linux process

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, intel-pin, page-tables

I am writing to inquire the feasibility of tracing the page table access (in terms of "index" of each page table access) of a common Linux user application. Basically, what I am doing is to re-produce the exploitation mentioned in this research article (https://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2015/papers-archived/6949a640.pdf).  In particular, the  **data-page accesses** need to be recorded for usage and inference of program secrets.

I understand the on Linux system, 64-bit x86 architecture, the page table size is 4K. And i have used `pin` (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) to log a trace of addresses for all virtual memory access. So can I simply calculate the "index" of each **data page table access**, with the following translation rule?

```
index = address >> 15
```

Since `4KB = 2 ^ 15`. Is it correct? Thank you in advance for any suggestions or comments.

Also, I think one thing I want to point out is that conceptually, I don't need a "precise" identifier of each data page table ID, but just a number ("index") to distinguish the access of different data pages. This shall provide conceptually identical amount of information compared with their attacks.

Comment: 4KB = 2^12.....

Comment: What is an "index" of page table access? Is this an index of a row in the table, which is used for address translation? Note, that x86 and x86_64 has **several** levels of page tables. So at a single address translation several tables are accessed, so it is unclear what your "index" represents.

Comment: What's `pin`? What do you mean by "index"? What are you *exactly* trying to achieve? Are you writing a kernel module? Are you working with an userspace program? Please clarify. Saying "page table index" alone does not mean much as Linux has several levels of page tables and each address corresponds to an index in each one of them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry for the confusion it has caused.. I updated my question with more information and reference. Could you please take a look and see if that makes more sense this time? Thank you!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli. Thank you! I updated my question with additional info. Could you kindly take a look and see if that makes sense? Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be to instument qemu to record memory accesses.

Comment: Keep in mind that pin performs memory accesses of its own and may change the place where memory allocations are made by the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you don't really need an "index", but just some unique identifier to distinguish different pages in the virtual address of a process.

In such case, then you can just do `address >> PAGE_SHIFT`. In x86 with 4KB pages [`PAGE_SHIFT` is `12`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.10/source/arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h#L10), so you can do:

```
page_id = address >> 12
```

Then if `address1` and `address2` correspond to the same page the `page_id` will be the same for both addresses.

Alternatively, to achieve the same result, you could do `address & PAGE_MASK`, where `PAGE_MASK` is just `0xfffffffffffff000` (that is `~((1UL << PAGE_SHIFT) - 1)`).

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much!